# Python code to click on anchor tag

Tags: python, xpath, onclick, click, anchor

I am writing a python code to automate a web page.
I need to click on play button to play the recording. But I am not able to do so through the code.

**Inspect element gives me this - outer HTML of 'play' :**

```
<div class="play">
<a id="sm_1855464769" class="sm2_button" href="#"> </a>
</div>
```

**Inspect element gives me this - Xpath of 'play' :**

```
//*[@id="recording_1855464769"]/div/div/div[8]
```

**The python code what i wrote is :**

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(EC.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recording_1855464769']/div/div/div[8]"))
element.click()
```

**Error message what I get in the terminal :**

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(EC.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='recording_1855464769']/div/div/div[8]")))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

I need to click on the anchor tag in order to play the audio. How can I do that ?? Plz help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `By`. Replace `EC.find_element_by_xpath` with `By.XPATH`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    

element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located
              (By.XPATH("//*[@id='recording_1855464769']/div/div/div[8]"))
```

Comment: I got an alternate too.. 

     `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.play").click()`

     `driver.find_element_by_id("sm_1855464769").click()`

Comment: To make it **wait**...

    `element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.play')))`
 
    `element.click()`